# Let $[0,1]=\cup A_n$ and assume that $\lambda(A_i\cap E_j) \to 0$ as $j\to \infty$ for all $i$. Show that $\lambda(E_j)\to 0$ ($E_j\subseteq [0,1]$)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $[0,1]=\cup A_n$ and assume that $\lambda(A_i\cap E_j) \to 0$ as $j\to \infty$ for all $i$. Show that $\lambda(E_j)\to 0$ ($E_j\subseteq [0,1]$)

My proof: Assume towards contradiction that is not the case. Then there is a subsequence s.t $\lambda(E_{n_k})>\epsilon_0$ for some $\epsilon_0>0$. Now we can select a sequence s.t $\lambda(A_i\cap E_i)<\frac{\epsilon_0}{2^i}$ for each $i$ where $E_i$ is an element of our subsequence. This implies that $\lambda(\cup (A_i \cap E_i))<\sum\frac{\epsilon_0}{2^i}=\epsilon$ so $\lambda(\cup E_i)<\epsilon_0$ which is a contradiction.

Is this correct? Is there a better cleaner proof?

Comment: You claim: Now we can select a sequence s.t $\lambda(A_i\cup E_i)<\frac{\epsilon_0}{2^i}$ for each $i$ where $E_i$ is an element of our subsequence. Why is this true?

Comment: @jflipp It should be cap (i fixed it), and that is because it converges to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step "we can select a sequence s.t $\lambda(A_i\cap E_i)<\frac{\epsilon_0}{2^i}$ for each $i$" has to be made more precise. It is not clear a priori that $\lambda(A_{n_k}\cap E_{n_k})$ goes to zero. However, we know that for all fixed $i$, $\lambda(A_{i}\cap E_{n_k})\to 0$ as $k$ goes to infinity. We can choose $k_i$ such that $\lambda(A_{i}\cap E_{n_{k_i}})\leqslant 2^{-i-1}\epsilon_0$. Then

$$
\epsilon_0\leqslant \lambda\left(\bigcup_{i\geqslant 1}E_{n_{k_i}}\right)
\leqslant \lambda\left(\bigcup_{i\geqslant 1}\left(E_{n_{k_i}}\cap A_i\right)\right)
+\lambda\left(\left(\bigcup_{i\geqslant 1}A_i\right)^c\right)\leqslant 2^{-1}\epsilon_0,$$
a contradiction.

Alternatively, suppose without loss of generality that $(A_i)$ is pairwise disjoint (replace $A_i$ by $A_i\setminus \bigcap_{k=1}^{i-1}A_k^c$ if necessary). Let $c_{i,j}:=\lambda\left(A_i\cap E_j\right)$. We know that for all $i$, $c_{i,j}\to 0$ and $\sup_{j\geqslant 1}\lvert c_{i,j}\rvert\leqslant \lambda(A_i)$ hence $\sum_{i\geqslant 1}\sup_{j\geqslant 1}\lvert c_{i,j}\rvert$ is summable. Apply the dominated convergence theorem to get that $\sum_{i\geqslant 1}c_{i,j}\to 0$, which translates (since the $A_i$ are disjoint) into $\lambda(E_j)\to 0$.

Comment: Here is my reasoning as to why we can pick such a sequence. For each $i$, there is $M$ s.t $j>M$ implies $\lambda(A_i\cap E_j)<\frac{\epsilon_0}{2^i}$. Now since we have a sequence of $E_{n_k}$ we know that eventually $n_k>M$ and so we simply pick the first element for which that is the case. this is basically what you said. Thank you for the help. The second solution is interesting! btw, big fan of some of your answers here on stack, very enlightening/.